# How to calculate the mean of points each of which is of d-dimension

Tags: dataset, cluster-analysis, mean, k-means

In `kmeans` clustering algorithm, when each point is of d-dimensional size, how do I calculate the mean of all points? In other word, my question here is actually how to perform the mean operation when points are of dimension more than 1.

For instance, suppose my dataset is of 3-dim. Assume there is a cluster with a centroid `[1,2,3]` and its points are `[3,5,4], [4,6,2], [6,5,7], [8,1,2]`, now I don't know how to perform the mean between these 4 points  since every point is of 3D.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do the same thing as in one dimension for each dimension. For the points `[3,5,4], [4,6,2], [6,5,7], [8,1,2]` you would get `[5.25, 4.25, 3.75]`

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much